# Is it possible to customize the title of an Windows Authentication credentials dialog prompt?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I am building a central intranet web portal that provides access to various other web applications and tools. Several of the target web applications are hosted on external companies' web servers running IIS with Windows Authentication enabled.

The problem I have is each of these external sites prompts for the users' security credentials, but without supplying the context of which site is requesting the credentials. Assuming the users' credentials are different across each of these sites, it can be difficult for them to know which username/password to supply at each of these target endpoints.

Is it possible to customize the title of these Windows Authentication prompt dialogs? I'd like to show the domain name for the server requesting credentials. Or would this present a security risk?

I can set requirements on each of these sites to implement a solution to this problem, or provide a reusable piece of code to them.

I found [this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hostname-in-titlebar/?src=api) for Firefox, but I really need this to be cross-browser. Can it be achieved with client- or server-side JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible to identify the server requesting credentials, and for good reason: to prevent spoofing a banking site in order to collect accounts, etc. Someone please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

Instead, I'll put up a simple label or dialog box so the user has some cue where the request is coming from.